# Wifi won't turn back on after I accidentally turned it off

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wifi-driver

I accidentally pressed `Fn`+`F12` on my **HP dv6** laptop, 
which turns off my Wifi. When I tried to do the same to turn it
back on, it said "Airplane Mode Off" on the screen, but wifi still
wouldn't work again. I tried pressing it a few more times but all
I was doing was turning Airplane Mode On and Off.

I restarted my computer, but still Wifi wouldn't come back on. All I see is a little `x` over 
the signals icon you would normally press to select a network.

How can I get my Wifi to work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by going to **Device Manager**

```
Start > "Device Manager"
```

Opening the **Network Adapters** section. Clicking on the Wifi device (in my case `Ralink RT5390R`), clicking on the `Advanced Tab`, selecting **Radio On/Off** and then on the right side, selecting `Enable` from the dropdown.

Now it works!

Comment: Additionally you can try to delete the hardware driver and restart your laptop to make it detect wifi device and install it again . This can solve the issue too.